# Using random numbers with usleep()

Tags: c++, pointers, random, reference, usleep

I notice each time that I run my program the random number, represented by percentage, is always climbing. As in, the previous random number is always smaller than the next random number. What can I do to keep this from happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Simulation.h"

void runOneGame();


int main(void){

Simulation playGame;

playGame.runOneGame();

  
  return 0;
}

#ifndef SIMULATION_H
#define SIMULATION_H

class Simulation{
private:
    int harePosition, turtlePosition;
public:
    Simulation() {};
    void moveTortoise(unsigned int *ptrTurtle);
    void moveHare(unsigned int *ptrHare);
    void runOneGame(); 
};

#endif

#include "Simulation.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>

void Simulation::moveTortoise(unsigned int *ptrTurtle){
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    int percentage = rand() % 100 + 1;
    
    std::cout  << percentage << "%" << std::endl;
    
    if(percentage >= 50){ *ptrTurtle += 3; } //fast pace 50% 3 squares forward
    else if(percentage < 50 && percentage >= 25){ *ptrTurtle += 1; } //slow pace 25% 1 square forward
    else if(*ptrTurtle > 6 && percentage < 25){ *ptrTurtle -= 6; }  //slip 25% 6 squares backward
    else{ *ptrTurtle = 1; }  // set block position to 1 when block position is less than 6
    
    std::cout << "T " << *ptrTurtle << std::endl;

}

void Simulation::moveHare(unsigned int *ptrHare) {
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    int percentage = rand() % 100 + 1;
    
    if(percentage >= 70){ *ptrHare += 1;} //small hop 30% 1 square forward
    else if(percentage >= 45 && percentage < 70){ *ptrHare = *ptrHare; } //sleep 25% No move
    else if(percentage >= 25 && percentage < 45) { *ptrHare += 9; } //big hop 2O% 9 squares forward
    else if(*ptrHare > 2 && percentage >= 5 && percentage < 25){ *ptrHare -= 2; } //small slip 20% 2 squares backwards
    else if(*ptrHare > 12 && percentage >= 1 && percentage < 5) { *ptrHare -= 12; } //big slip 5% 12 squares backward
    else {*ptrHare = 1; } // set block position to 1 when block position is less than squares backwards

    std::cout << "H " << *ptrHare << std::endl;

}

void Simulation::runOneGame(){
    
    unsigned int turtlePosition, harePosition = 1; //starting position
    unsigned int *ptrTurtle = &turtlePosition;
    unsigned int *ptrHare = &harePosition;
    
    bool iterate = true;
    int loop = 1;

    //std::cout << "OUCH!" << std::endl;
    
    while(usleep(1000000) == 0 && iterate){
      
      std::cout << loop << std::endl;
      if(*ptrTurtle == *ptrHare){std::cout << "OUCH!" << std::endl;}
      moveTortoise(ptrTurtle);
      moveHare(ptrHare);
     
      
      if(*ptrHare >= 70){iterate = false; std::cout << "HARE WINS!" << std::endl;}
      if(*ptrTurtle >= 70) {iterate = false; std::cout << "TORTOISE WINS!" << std::endl;}
      
      std::cout << std::endl;
      loop++;
    } 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

1
OUCH!
35%
T 2
H 10

2
42%
T 3
H 19

3
49%
T 4
H 19

4
56%
T 7
H 19

5
63%
T 10
H 19

6
70%
T 13
H 20

7
77%
T 16
H 21

8
84%
T 19
H 22

9
91%
T 22
H 23

10
98%
T 25
H 24

11
5%
T 19
H 22

12
12%
T 13
H 20

13
19%
T 7
H 18

14
26%
T 8
H 27

15
33%
T 9
H 36

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages in your question, only the language you're actually program in.

Comment: As a probable hint to your problem: Only call `srand` ***once***. Or don't use `srand`/`rand` at all, and instead use the "new" C++ [random number generation facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: You should run `seed()` only once in `main()`.

Comment: Here's a [minimal example](https://godbolt.org/z/Kx7G3Kvzb) of what your problem is and [here's the cure](https://godbolt.org/z/ax1h6bh7P) - but you should really be using `<random>` instead